# Can Visual Studio warn me when I forget to dispose an IDisposable object?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, idisposable, compiler-warnings

Can Visual Studio 2008 be configured to give me a warning when I forget to dispose an object that implements IDisposable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio, by itself does not have this feature, but with [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/index.xml) you can have design time warnings and refactorings to insert using blocks where needed.

Comment: ReSharper will do this as well.

Comment: CodeRush Xpress is even available FOR FREE:   http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/

Comment: FxCop and Genderme will do this as well (both free)

Comment: @JohnSaunders Are you sure? I can't find the option by searching for "dispos".

Comment: @jeromej It's not an option. It's one of the quick fixes.

Answer (score 3):

If you turn on FxCop Design rules it will tell you when you don't implement IDisposable and you have members which implement IDisposable, like this:

```
class Program
{
    private DataTable NotDisposed;

    public Program()
    {
        NotDisposed = new DataTable();
    }
    static void Main()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: FxCop is great for this kind of stuff.  'course it would be nice if visual studio actually warned you if you made a mistake using (or implementing IDisposable), but heck.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be done at compile time.

however, it can be done at runtime.
I have created an abstract class 'Disposable' (which implements IDisposable, and implements the Disposable pattern).
In the finalizer, I issue an Assert when the finalizer is called, and the object has not been disposed.

I've based this on an article of Ian Griffiths:

http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/04/26/yetmoretimedlocking

Comment: I would argue against having a base class for handling disposal. Since .NET is single-inheritance, this locks you in to a very strict inheritance chain that requires your DisposeBase to be at the top.

Comment: besides that you could just use "System.ComponentModel.Component"